# Entity Framework Map String to datetime column

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

I have a class with some string properties that represent dates in an arbitrary format.  These need to remain as String properties. Is there a way, using the fluent API or something, to indicate that these column types should be datetime.  And then somehow I can tell EF to marshal the data in a certain way?

Can I just use:

```
HasColumnType("datetime")
```

and if so, how would I then handle the marshalling?

Example Class:

```
public Class SomePOCO{

    public String SomeTimeInWierdFormat { get; set; }
    public String SomeOtherTimeInWierdFormat { get; set; }
    public String SomeString{ get; set; }
}
```

Is there a string format that I can massage these strings into that would allow me use HasColumnType("datetime") without any complaints?

Comment: why you want to keep the property as `string` ?

Comment: Lets just say it has to be that way, I have no control over that.

Comment: Then why can't you store them as strings in DB as well and then convert them to dates on output?

Comment: They have to be stored as dates for some other application to use.

Comment: there has to be a better way.  "I want a datetime to store a string" is silly/ridiculous.

Comment: Is is possible for you to add another property to this type, which returns the formatted string?

Comment: Yea, i guess i could do that.  I guess that makes the most sense

Comment: If it needs to be a string is some other layer of the application, I suggest you keep it as a DateTime on your entity, and use a DTO/ViewModel/Whatever to make it a String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use read only properties to expose your `DateTimes` as formatted `strings`.  This is useful because way you can still have properties that correctly map to the database while exposing that data however you choose.  Maybe something like this:

```
public Class SomePOCO{

    public DateTime DateTimeColumn { get; set; }
    public string DateTimeColumnAsString { get { return this.DateTimeColumn.ToString(); } }

}
```

Comment: It should probably be marked as not mapped so that EF doesn't persist the string.

Comment: Is that necessary since `DateTimeColumnAsString` doesn't have a setter?

Comment: It seems to make sense that there would be a convention for that, but I would have to try to see.